# Ajax postback not working for a page inside a directory?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net web application,not MVC..so no controllers.In my UI i have a folder inside that folder i have my page
The java script post back i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRepositoryDetailsFK() {
        debugger;

        var myurl = "../MYFOLDER/MYPAGE.aspx/mymethod";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            url: myurl,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {


            },
            success: function(data) {


            },

            error: function(ex) {

            },
            complete: function() {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

in my .axpx.cs page

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public void mymethod()
        {

        }
```

i have followed 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx

but dont know its not hitting the method..Any help?

Comment: What control executes GetRepositoryDetailsFK()?

Comment: `mymethod` must be a static

Comment: Its Asp button ..<asp:Button ID="btnDelete1" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return GetRepositoryDetailsFK();" />

Comment: Won't it work if its not static

Comment: Actually in my case i can't make my method static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method has to be static as mentioned in that example.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string mymethod()
{
    //do something
}
```

This is due to the fact that the call isn’t a true call to the entire page lifecycle. [Reference](http://www.jbcdigital.com/call-non-static-server-side-methods-via-microsofts-ajax.aspx)

Alternatively, use asp.net webservices(.asmx) to write web methods which can be called using ajax. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529847/Calling-ASP-NET-WebService-from-jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRepositoryDetailsFK() {

        var myurl = "../MYFOLDER/MYPAGE.aspx/mymethod";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: myurl,
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(ex) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```